# How to restrict entering special characters into Kendo grid input column

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid with a description column. How do I restrict the user from entering special characters into it? My Kendo grid column field is as below.

```
{ field : "myDesc", width : 200, title : "My Description"}
```

So far I have done as below...but no luck.

```
{ 
  field : "myDesc",
  width : 200,
  title : "My Description",
  editor: function(container, options) { 
              $('<input type="text" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9]" class="k-input k-textbox">')
                  .appendTo(container); 
          },
  attributes : {
                "class":"table-cell",
                style:"text-align: left;
                       white-space:nowrap;
                       overflow:hidden;
                       text-overflow:ellipsis;"
               }
}
```

I want to restrict entering special characters like `~_!@#$%^&*()+=-[]\\\';,./{}|\":<>?`

**Update**

Well, I missed to let you guys know that I am using the kendo UI grid wit AngularJS. I tried Marco suggested solution by modifying my code in Angular way. Still no luck.

```
{ field : "myDesc", width : 200, title : "My Description", 
                                    editor: function(container, options) { 
                                          $('<input type="text" class="k-input k-textbox" ng-keypress="isValidChar($event)">').appendTo(container); 
                                    },
                                    attributes : {"class":"table-cell",style:"text-align: left;white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;"}},
```

And my function as below.

```
$scope.isValidChar = function(e) {
                var match = e.key.match(/[a-zA-Z0-9]/);
                return  match ? true : false; 
            };
```

And also I see one more issue here, when I focus out whatever I entered is not updated and it is shows the previous value.

Attaching the screen shot here. Sorry I have to mask few things on screenshot for privacy purpose.

[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbl4P.png)

Comment: What do you define as special characters? And why don't you want them?

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: So far I have done as below...but no luck

Comment: { field : "myDesc", width : 200, title : "My Description", 
 editor: function(container, options) { 
  $('<input type="text" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9]" class="k-input k-textbox">').appendTo(container);
 },
 attributes : {"class":"table-cell",style:"text-align: left;white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;"}},

Comment: I want to restrict entering special characters like (# ^ | ....and few more).

Comment: Please edit your code into the question.
Do you have a longer list of acceptable characters (E.g. a-z,0-9) or an exact list of one's to be excluded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using the `onkeypress` event:

```
{ 
  field : "myDesc",
  width : 200,
  title : "My Description",
  editor: function(container, options) { 
              $('<input type="text" class="k-input k-textbox" onkeypress="return isValidChar(event)">')
                  .appendTo(container); 
          },
   /*...*/
}

function isValidChar(e) {
    var match = e.key.match(/[a-zA-Z0-9]/);
    return  match ? true : false; 
}
```

Demo: https://dojo.telerik.com/erIRUSiR/2

Comment: Hi Macro! Sorry...I think I messed up responding to your suggestion. I am new to asking questions on stackoverflow.

Comment: Does not matter. It works nontheless excactly the same: http://plnkr.co/edit/nd1bYcLVWUyeM9SJjRcw?p=preview

Comment: Hi Marco! Thank you for the help.